# Can I eat eggs that are cooked over 3 hours with low temperature looking a bit brown?

Tags: eggs

I wanted to try what happens to eggs over long cooking with low-temperature. The white thing became a bit brown and the odour is a bit different. Are they edible?

**[Update]**
I used the lowest temperature in a gas stove with a pressure heavy iron container thing.

I ate the eggs, the yellow tasted dry while the white tasted actually better than usually.

Comment: I doubt that they are editable, but they are certainly edible. Although your temperature wasn't very low if you got them brown.

Comment: @rumtscho: With a long enough cooking time, even ~100C will turn them brown!

Comment: @Jefromi 100°C is a simmer, so normal for eggs, not low. There was a link ghosting around - probably to Baldwin, I don't remember - which said that a restaurant will usually soft boil an egg at much lower for several hours, then keep it in a second chamber just above 60°C and serve it out of it. I don't think you can decompose the eggwhite at 60°C at all.

Comment: @rumtscho: Right, for some reason I was comparing to higher temperature baking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fine to eat, from a food safety perspective.  The heat will  be high enough to prevent bacterial growth.

I can't speak to the flavor, of course. Edible is a matter of opinion.  Goodness knows we've all eaten our culinary screwups that nobody else would touch at least once.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a screwup, either!

Answer (score 1):

Not only *can* you eat eggs that have turned brown during a long cooking period, you *should*! Something I came across a couple years back: [the 300 minute egg](http://fxcuisine.com/default.asp?language=2&Display=64). They're delicious, and I love the way they look, too.

Comment: +1 yes they were excellent, I am currently simmering a bunch of eggs for a night, 3k mins eggs :D I have last-day-marked eggs and I think dry culinary eggs will be cool...or perhaps I will cut them to pieces and then dry them...investigating.

Answer (score 0):

In the traditional Jewish Sabbath stew called [cholent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholent), the stew is put in the oven before the end of the day on Friday. It's cooked overnight and eaten at lunch on Saturday. The Sephardis (North African, Spanish, or Arab areas) often put whole eggs in the shell into the cholent.

[This recipe](http://jewishmag.com/43mag/cholent/cholent.htm) claims that the eggs are the star of the show. Here are [some](http://kosherfood.about.com/od/sabbathcooking/r/cholent_meat.htm) [other](http://www.suite101.com/content/cholent-jewish-beef-stew-a21609) [recipes](http://www.latimes.com/features/food/la-fo-cholent-s,0,2859580.story). (Including in a [crock pot](http://www.cooks.com/rec/doc/0,1918,154183-246203,00.html).)